# pg_dumpall save results to another server?

Tags: postgresql

I have used most of the space on my Postgres server and I can not save the results of pg_dumpall on my machine. Is there anyway to get the results of pg_dumpall to another server while pg_dumpall is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pg_dumpall` is a *client* application. It can run on any computer that can (remotely) connect to the Postgres server.

So you can run `pg_dumpall` on the server that has space, connecting to the actual database server using the `--host=...` parameter.

Or you can store the output of `pg_dumpall` on a network drive.